# how to show products under the categories on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

am working on a rails app and on the show page for a category, i want to show all the products found under that category
 here is how my

show in category is

```
def show
    @products = Category.friendly.where(params[:name])
  end
```

and in my views i have it like this

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>

<%= link_to product_path(id: product.slug, category_name: product.category.name), class: "card" do %>
<div class="product-image">
<%= image_tag product.productpic.url if product.productpic? %>
</div>

  <div class="product-text">
    <h2 class="product-title"> <%= product.name %></h2>
      <h3 class="product-price">£<%= product.price %></h3>
  </div>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

here is my products model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  mount_uploader :productpic, ProductpicUploader
   has_many :order_items
acts_as_taggable
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
 default_scope { where(active: true) }
end
```

and my category like this

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Do you get an error message? Does it not display what you'd like? What does it display?

Comment: i get `undefined method `category' for #<Category:0x007f8c00ad4858>`

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace and show models/category.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You finder gets the categor**ies**, not the products:

```
def show
  @categories = Category.friendly.where(params[:name])
end
```

If you have proper relations, you can iterate each product in the given category. Since the method `where` returns relation, first you need is iterate through it.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% category.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product-category">
      Category:
      <%= product.category.name %>
    </div>
    <div class="product-text">
      <h2 class="product-title"> <%= product.name %></h2>
      <h3 class="product-price">£<%= product.price %></h3>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: am getting undefine method products

Comment: Please show your models - product.rb and category.rb

Comment: i get ``undefined method `each' for #<Category:0x007f44009b0190>

Comment: Very strange. Run `rails c` and execute commands step by step.
`@categories = Category.friendly.where(<category_name>)`
Show me `@categories`; explore it.

Comment: i run it like this `@categories = Category.friendly.where(name:"clothing")
  Category Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = $1  [["name", "clothing"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 2, name: "clothing"`

Answer (score 0):

you are executing a wrong query. You are taking `category` that is fine but you have to take related `products` that is what you need.

it should be like,
`@products = Category.friendly.where(name: params[:name]).first.products`

then in the view code, you can iterate over products of a category.

Comment: how will i do that?

Comment: you just replace your query with mine which I posted in answer and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def show
  category = Category.friendly.find_by_name(params[:name])
  @products = category.products
end
```

Comment: `undefined method `products' for #<Category`

Comment: Product is belongs to Category or not ?
product table must have category_id